# any performance difference or better code reuse between tagging a UIElement or subclassing a control?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uielement

I'm wondering if there is any difference between these two approaches of setting properties on a `UITableViewCell`.

Option A:
In your storyboard file, on your `UITableViewCell`, drag your `UIElement`s onto the `UITableViewCell`, tag each `UIelement`.  Then in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReuseableCellIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

   UILabel *aLabel = [cell viewWithTag:TAG_FROM_IB];
   aLabel.text = @"my text";

   UIImageView *aImageView = [cell viewWithTag:TAG_FROM_IB];
   aImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];

   return cell;
}
```

option B:
Drag the `UIElement`s onto the `UITableViewCell` in the storyboard.  Create a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`, change the class of the `UITableViewCell` to your new custom subclass, access the properties by:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReuseableCellIdentifier:@"MyTableViewCell"];

   cell.aLabel.text = @"my text";

   cell.aImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];

   return cell;
}
```

I was just wondering if there was a "preferred" or "better" way to create custom `UITableViewCell`s.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

definitly no. two!

it much more concise: cleaner and clearer to use then! performance wise it is also superior BUT thats not a measurable amount...

+(IMHO) performance should never be the **initial** reason for a design decision.